# Installer offers ext2 as a filesystem for main partition in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 16.04, filesystem

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 16.04. When it comes to the partitioning after using the "guided LVM" option Ubuntu will offer the following filesystems for the partitions:

- ext4 for root
- swap for swap (sic!)
- ext2 for main partition

So I was curious about why is it so? I'm not very good in Linux yet but my understanding is that ext3 is a bit more safe in terms of storing data with not much overhead for journalling. And also there is ext4 already there, obviously quite stable as it is used for root partition. So could anyone explain what is the idea behind still having ext2 as a default filesystem in 16.04?

Comment: Sound worthy of a bug report.

Comment: What's the "main partition"? If you mean the *boot* partition then yes, ext2 is a perfectly good choice, because (1) ext2 has much less metadata overhead (and the boot partition is small) and (2) the boot partition is only rarely modified, so the use of a journalling filesystem won't be of much utility.

Comment: @AlexP your comment could be posted as an answer